# How to update one or some property(ies) in JSON file with nested data whilst preserving structure?

Tags: c#, json

My json file looks like this

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "Delay": 1000
    }
}
```

I only want to change the "Delay" property. I can't figure it out for the life of me. On YouTube they only show  fairly linear examples and other goodies not related to my question. It's a .net Core project and I'm not even sure whether I should install Newstonsoft.json (according to the mighty YouTube System.Text.Json is almost identical).

So if anyone could help me out, that would be great. I don't even know what datastructure I am supposed to make for a structure like this. Again because the examples available mention the most simple structures only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need only several lines of code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var path=@"C:\...";
var json = File.ReadAllText(path);

var jObj = JsonConvert.Parse(json);

jObj["Parameters"]["Delay"] = 2000;

json = jObj.ToString();

File.WriteAllText(path, json);
```

Comment: So I am to install Newtonsoft.json, right? Because I don't recognize JObject.

Comment: @Valmont Yes, you have to install and add  a using  namespace.... I updated my answer

Comment: Hours of fiddling... I won't forget this one. For my learning experience, how should I have taught myself this? I may need to improve my ways of learning.

Comment: @Valmont Practice makes perfect, you have to excersize